# Dynamic field validation message issue

Tags: validation, dynamic, field, message

1.I have added dynamic array field which changes on the dropdown. and I have added "required" in html

```
 $.each(data.result, function (key, value) {
    if (typeof value['filter'] !== "undefined") {
        var id = value['filter']['id'];
        var name = value['filter']['name'];
        $(".label_filter2").append('<div class="form-group m-form__group"><label class="custom_form_label">' + name + '<span class="error_msg">*</span></label><input type="text" class="form-control m-input m-input--air filter_specification" name="filter[' + id + ']" placeholder="Enter ' + name + '" data-toggle="m-tooltip" required title="' + name + '"></div>');
    }
});
```

2.Its totally work, but problem is validation message same like label.

https://www.screencast.com/t/Hqawm0Tae

3.I need "this field is require" message.I hope you are  understand my question.Please help me.

Comment: try to add your code in the post, it's better than image

Comment: Please check edit post

Comment: Yes , and i got this result.                                                                                                             (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: 82, filter_id: 11, category_id: 11, value: null, created_at: "2019-03-11 19:29:10", …}
1: {id: 129, filter_id: 24, category_id: 11, value: null, created_at: "2019-03-13 00:46:31", …}
2: {id: 137, filter_id: 25, category_id: 11, value: null, created_at: "2019-04-01 18:44:55", …}
length: 3

Comment: can you try to reproduce the issue in https://jsfiddle.net/ and post the link ? you can use a fake data.result

Comment: I don't think so.I have no idea.

Comment: I have lost of code in project

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191085/discussion-between-fraction-and-manisha).